# Bash - Calculate average and frequency of a column

Tags: bash, awk

I'm running a shell script that performs a load test on my service. At the end of the test, I get a file that looks like this:

```
200    2.691
200    2.735
404    1.997
404    2.838
200    1.394
200    1.833
```

I'd like to calculate the min, max and mean response time for every unique HTTP response code. Something like this -

```
http    min    max    mean    count
200    1.394  2.735   2.163    4
404    1.997  2.838   2.418    2
```

The output originates from this command (if that helps):

`curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\t%{time_total}\n" $SERVICE_URL`

Can someone share pointers on how I can go about achieving this in bash? I looked at http://cacodaemon.de/index.php?id=11 for ideas but couldn't make anything work.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you definite about having to use Bash+AWK? Because there are much better alternatives available: spreadsheets, Python, Ruby or even Perl. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @l0b0 I actually think `awk` is easier for this than `perl`.  `awk` handles column/field splitting just a *tiny* bit more effortlessly and its "associative array" syntax is way less easy to mess up than perl's hash variable syntax, which still hurts my brain.  I'd personally use `perl` for this, but only to train myself for when I need access to capture groups, etc..

Comment: @l0b0 - See my perl answer.  Maybe there's a smarter way to approach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    min[$1] = ( ($1 in min) && (min[$1] < $2) ? min[$1] : $2 )
    max[$1] = ( ($1 in max) && (max[$1] > $2) ? max[$1] : $2 )
    sum[$1] += $2
    cnt[$1]++
}
END {
    print "http", "min", "max", "mean", "cnt"
    for (key in cnt) {
        print key, min[key], max[key], sprintf("%.3f",sum[key]/cnt[key]), cnt[key]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
http  min    max    mean   cnt
200   1.394  2.735  2.163  4
404   1.997  2.838  2.417  2
```

The above will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Comment: Nice and clean.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks Ed.

Answer (score 2):

Columnize by whitespace `-W` Group by column 1 `-g 1`, print outputs for column 2 based on grouping:

```
datamash -sW -g 1 min 2 max 2 mean 2 count 2 <dmInput
```

To see more of what's going on:

```
datamash --header-out -sW -g 1 min 2 max 2 mean 2 count 2 <dmInput | column -t
```

And...if you really want to use `awk`, you can use it to add column names:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "HttpCode ResponseTime";} {print}' dmInput | datamash -sWH -g HttpCode min ResponseTime max ResponseTime mean ResponseTime count ResponseTime | column -t
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the baseline perl (no CPAN allowed because just use my datamash answer at that point) equivalent for Ed's answer.  As noted, just a tiny bit nastier in every way:

```
£ cat tst.pl
$min{$F[0]} = $F[1] if !(exists $min{$F[0]}) || $F[1] < $min{$F[0]};
$max{$F[0]} = $F[1] if !(exists $max{$F[0]}) || $F[1] > $max{$F[0]};
$sum{$F[0]} += $F[1]; 
$cnt{$F[0]}++;
END
{
      print "http min max mean cnt";
      for $key (keys %cnt) 
           {print "$key $min{$key} $max{$key} @{[$sum{$key}/$cnt{$key}]} $cnt{$key}";}
}
£ perl -lan tst.pl dmInput | column -t
http  min    max    mean     cnt
404   1.997  2.838  2.4175   2
200   1.394  2.735  2.16325  4
```

Answer (score -1):

use awk array

```
cat 1.txt | nawk '{s[$1]+=$2;c[$1]++;max[$1]=max[$1]>$2?max[$1]:$2;min[$1]=min[$1]==0?$2:min[$1]>=$2?$2:min[$1]} END{for(i in s) print i","min[i]","max[i]","s[i]/c[i]","c[i]}'  | sort
200,1.394,2.735,2.16325,4
404,1.997,2.838,2.4175,2
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49911096/1745001) but minus the header, with a UUOC, and crammed onto 1 line!

Comment: Sorry I jumped straight from the question to answer and didn't read your answer. It's long so I thought it was a shell script. apologies

Comment: No problem. wrt the length of my script, it's as brief as it has to be to be easily understandable. Using single-character variables and cramming naturally multi-line scripts onto one line is not useful. Brevity is not a goal of software development, conciseness is. btw on a second read your script isn't exactly the same as mine - yours will fail if all of the $2 values are negative. It's hard to spot then when it's all crammed onto 1 line.